# What does base -2 mean?

Tags: base-conversion, radix

Can anyone help me understand what is base -2? I understand base in positive integers and know how to convert a decimal number to those bases, but really do not have any idea with negative base.

Comment: what language did you prefer?? python or in general??

Answer (score 0):

This exotic base descried in the book: http://www.hackersdelight.org/hacker2TOC.pdf
And, is not practical.

But, basic idea as same as with a regular binary code:

ABCD == A*(-2)^3 + B*(-2)^2 + C*(-2) + D

Example of numbers:

```
-2          Decimal
-------------------
000              0
001              1
010             -2
011             -1
100              4
101              5
```

And so on.